# How do I make DBX know that fields from joins shouldn't be updated during ApplyUpdates?

Tags: sql, delphi, join, dbexpress

I've got some code that builds a map (graph) of rooms on a grid with links between them.  It's stored in a Firebird database with rooms in one table and links in another.  The data is managed through DB Express TSimpleDataset datasets.

The query for the Exits (links) table looks like this:

```
select
  EXITS.*,
  r1.x as x,
  r1.y as y,
  r2.x as x2,
  r2.y as y2 
from EXITS
inner join ROOMS r1 on r1.ROOM_ID = EXITS.ROOM1
inner join ROOMS r2 on r2.ROOM_ID = EXITS.ROOM2
```

Problem is, when I add a new exit and call ApplyUpdates, DBX's SQL parser doesn't seem to understand that the fields from the ROOMS table are just there for convenience and not part of the original table.  It generates the following:

```
insert into "EXITS"
  ("EXIT_ID", "AORDER", "AEXIT", "PREACTION", "POSTACTION", "COLOR", "ROOM1",
   "ROOM2", "MAP1", "MAP2", "X", "Y", "X2", "Y2")
values
  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

plus the appropriate params, with predictable results.  Does anyone know how I can make it understand that the Xs and Ys aren't supposed to be inserted or updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use provider flags to tell which fileds should be updated, and tell the provider which table shoud be updated (there's an OnGetTableName event or something alike). Another options is to use the OnBeforeUpdateRecord event and write some code to perform the update without using TDatasetProvider built in SQL generator.

Comment: Thanks.  Setting the ProviderFlags worked.  The only catch was that I had to put it on the AfterOpen event of the internal dataset for it to work right.

Comment: did you try the same whith tsqlquery + tdatasetprovider + tclientdataset ?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL for that Query is, well, a query intented for returning data, and is not appropiate for and Insert or Update. Eventhough SimpleDataSets allow for bidirectional usage, not all situations can be handled with it. I would create two different unidirectional ClientDataSet one for the Query and the other with a direct access to the Table instead of using the Query.

Quoting from Getting Started with dbExpress by Martin Rudy:

> A more appropriate approach is to use
>   a ClientDataSet (CDS) and
>   DataSetProvider. Connecting to data
>   using a CDS and DSP  Both the CDS and
>   DSP components are located on the Data
>   Access component palette.  A
>   SQLDataSet component from the
>   dbExpress palette is used to define
>   the result set.  The SQLConnection
>   property of the SQLDataSet is assigned
>   to the SQLConnection component name. 
>   The SQLDataSet CommandText property
>   defines the SQL statement. The DataSet
>   property of the DSP is set to the name
>   of the SQLDataSet component.  The CDS
>   component has a ProviderName property
>   which is set to the DSP name.  The
>   last property value change is to the
>   DataSource DataSet property which
>   should be assigned to the CDS
>   component name.  Setting the CDS
>   Active property to True (or using the
>   Open method) retrieves the data. At
>   first glance you might feel this is
>   too much work compared to the
>   SimpleClientDataSet.  As we cover more
>   of the CDS and DSP features you gain a
>   better understanding of why you will
>   use a DSP and CDS instead of the
>   SimpleClientDataSet

Also, read the chapter on Setting **UpdateMode** and **ProviderFlags** properties

There is a lot of interesting information regarding the control of the fields in the dataset used to find and update a record.

> Using ClientDataSets, the UpdateMode property is on the DataSetProvider.  If you use one of the combination CDS/DSP components (e.g. SimpleClientDataset), those components have an UpdateMode property because of the internal DataSetProvider.

Comment: When I said those extra fields are there for convenience, that was a bit of an understatement.  Taking them out would require massive rearchitecting and probably end up slowing the program down quite a bit, since I'd need to do all the join logic client-side.  There has to be a better way...

Comment: I meant to keep them on the query but to remove them from the table. I see I was oversimplifying. What aboyt using two separated datasets with different providerfields?